# Opening Liferay portal w/ Glassfish sends Octet/stream 32bytes in some browsers

Tags: file, stream, download, glassfish, liferay

I've been working with liferay for a while, and currently i'm trying to build a company's intranet but I'm facing this weird problem.

There's some "co-workers" here in the company that can't open this Liferay portal in some of their browsers. The thing is when they write the url on their browsers and press Enter key, a file called "home" gets downloaded instead of opening the liferay web page.
This happens for some users in Mozilla Firefox, for others in Google Chrome, for other in both of them. Some of these users use Windows 7 O.S, some others use Ubuntu 12.04.

We're using Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.0.5 CE (Bunyan / Build 6005 / August 16, 2010)
with Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1.2.2 (build 5).

We've worked with prior Glassfish versions like 2.1 and 2.1.1, but we had never faced an issue like this one.
As I said this happens for some users, for some others it works fine.

Does anyone know what's the cause of this behaviour? How could I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like an ancient problem that has been found all over the internet - a problem in the gzip filter (Liferay also had it).

You state that you're using 6.0.5, odds are that it wasn't fixed in that release. I can't find it, but [this](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-5244) issue is close. After all, the best recommendation is: Please update to the latest version to be back at a current version that gets more updates. Alternatively, deactivate gzip on Liferay (you can activate it on an Apache httpd sitting in front of Liferay)